# How to set zlim values in R-highcharter plots

Tags: r, r-highcharter

How does one control the z-axis for highcharter matrix plots in R?

```
library(highcharter)
data(volcano)
hchart(volcano/2, zlim=c(0,200))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the color-axis, then this is a way to control it:

```
library(highcharter)
data(volcano)
hc <- hchart(volcano/2) %>%
  hc_colorAxis(min = 0, max = 200)
hc
```

Basically you create a highcharter object using the function hchart then using the function hc_colorAxis you can modify the created object and get a new object in return.

[image]

For other nice examples of highcharter functions please see: http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts-api.html

And for info about the forward-pipe operator %>% you can see the documentation of package magrittr: https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr.
But magrittr is not needed here if you are using highcharter.